# whats wrong in this sql join syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this code but it doesn't feed me back with the right count (it comes back as 0 ) as there are many same values in each columns..do you have any idea what is wrong?

```
select count(*)
from "accidents"
inner join "Vechicles"
on 'accidents.Accident_Index'='Vechicles.Accident_Index';
```

Comment: What you want to achieve ? clarify it.

Comment: You're joining where *the string* `'accidents.Accident_Index'` matches *the string* `'Vechicles.Accident_Index'`. Get rid of the quotes.

Comment: It must surely be because the inner join returns no matches?

Comment: (Is it too late to correct the spelling of vehicles?)

Comment: Is it too late to get rid of those dreaded double quotes and re-create all tables without them?

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes `'` are for string constants, not for identifiers.

[Identifiers either need double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) `"` (which is not recommended) or nothing at all. And if you created your tables and columns using those dreaded double quotes, you need to quote each element individually, not everything as a single thing:

```
select count(*)
from "accidents"
  inner join "Vechicles"
     on "accidents"."Accident_Index" = "Vechicles"."Accident_Index";
```

The condition `'accidents.Accident_Index'='Vechicles.Accident_Index'` compares two string values that are not the same, so your statement is the same as:

```
select count(*)
from "accidents"
  inner join "Vechicles"
     on false
```

Comment: Thank you it worked with double quotes!